# Hash password with random salt using JavaScript and validate from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, hash

I want to make password maintain process strong for an asp.net web application. Please validate my idea if it is workable. If yes then please suggest sample code or links to implement. Otherwise suggest how can I send password securely from browser to server and store in hash.

**Note:** I am using TLS (SSL) already for security.

**Steps:**

1. While registering user, hash user password with random salt from
   JavaScript in Client browser.
2. Submit form.
3. Server side code will store the hash in database.
4. When user try to login, hash user password with random salt from JavaScript in Client browser.
5. Submit form.
6. Validate database stored hash with login password
   hash. (I am thinking both hash will be different due to random salt
   but verification function will be able to compare it)

Comment: Security is hard so don't mess with it unless you absolutely know what you're doing and even then you shouldn't implement your own solution. Just stick with well-proven techniques -> https://owasp.org

Comment: So basically you are storing the pre-hashed value on the server? So it is basically the same as storing a plain text value? In the end it is not secure because what ever the JS is doing can be seen by the user in the dev tools.

Comment: Don't go re-inventing something as easy to get wrong as user authentication. There's no difference between your hashed value and a password. We rely on TLS to keep things from prying eyes and accept that this is secure. If you're not well-versed in this sort of thing, use an off-the-shelf product such as aspnet identity. Years of research and best-practice can't be beaten unless you are an expert in this field. Why waste time on a solved problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not secure.** The hashing and salting should be a hidden implementation secret that the server provides, not the client. Since the client has the implementation secret, should someone gain access to your database, they can reverse engineer your security model.

HTTPS would protect the password in transit. I would also avoid rolling your own authentication system as there are many "gotchas". ASP.NET both Framework and Core provide strong patterns and implementations for authentication.

Comment: AFAIK hashing is not reversible then how this be reversed ?

Comment: @AjayNikam Using a rainbow table. You don't need to reverse the passwords, just find the matches

Comment: Submitting login(user ID, password) form without encryption or hashing, is it vulnerable?

Comment: @AjayNikam anything is "vulnerable". but if you properly use https, it should reduce the chance for a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: I didn't understand, what is the role of many JavaScript crypto libraries? Are the adding significant value in security?

Comment: @AjayNikam it depends on where that's being run. you would have to ask the maintainers of those libraries for their motivation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for helping to understand. I was confused due to multiple client side encryption articles on internet.